# What is the easiest way to filter a list in Java?

Tags: java

Currently when I want to filter a list I use to iterate over its elements and copy the elements that match my requirements to a new list but in this way I'm using O(2N) of spatial complexity. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 you could simply use myList.stream().filter();
Otherwise you could adopt the [Filter Pattern](http://erikras.com/2008/01/18/the-filter-pattern-java-conditional-abstraction-with-iterables/).

```
public abstract class Filter<T> {
public abstract boolean passes(T object);
public Iterator<T> filter(Iterator<T> iterator) {
return new FilterIterator(iterator);
  }
  public Iterable<T> filter(Iterable<T> iterable) {
  return new Iterable<T>() {
  public Iterator<T> iterator() {
    return filter(iterable.iterator());
    }
  };
 }
private class FilterIterator implements Iterator<T> {
private Iterator<T> iterator;
private T next;
private FilterIterator(Iterator<T> iterator) {
  this.iterator = iterator;
  toNext();
}
public boolean hasNext() {
  return next != null;
}
public T next() {
  if (next == null)
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
  T returnValue = next;
  toNext();
  return returnValue;
}
public void remove() {
  throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
private void toNext() {
  next = null;
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    T item = iterator.next();
    if (item != null && passes(item)) {
      next = item;
      break;
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will always have O(2N) spatial complexity if you need to keep the old list as well as construct the new list.

If you don't need to do a deep copy, store references in the new list. That is, inside your loop, instead of something like `newlist.add(item.deepClone())`, just do `newlist.add(item)`.

If you don't need to keep the old list, you could throw out the elements that *don't* match your requirements. E.g. inside your loop, instead of `if (isAKeeper(item)) newlist.add(...)`, use `if (!isAKeeper(item)) oldList.remove(item)`.